# How do I match 09 OR 12 inside a number with regex

Tags: regex

What is the range of | operator in a regex? and why? how can I control the range of this operator? So that it does not compare 1 digit before it with one digit after it, but 2,3 or more digits before with 2,3 or more digits after.
example:

```
\d\d(0[1-9])|(1[0-2])\d\d
```

But by parentheses I mean sticking those 2 numbers together

Comment: Do you want `((09)|(12))`?

Comment: You should make a simple change to your regex pattern, just change yours to `\d\d((0[1-9])|(1[0-2]))\d\d`.

Comment: Thanks!! @Azhy That is what I wanted. Sorry for not explaining very clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `|` in these `()` brackets, and if not it works for all the pattern, for yours the wrong was using `|` or `OR` operator without a bracket and because of that it matched all of the left part or all of the right part of the pattern:-

> Yours:-

```
\d\d(0[1-9])|(1[0-2])\d\d
```

> Solution:-

```
\d\d((0[1-9])|(1[0-2]))\d\d
```